# How to prevent Microsoft Word from changing template heading styles?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, office365, templates

I have defined custom font styles for Heading 1, Heading 2, etc., most notably from blue color to black. I saved the changes into the Normal.dotm and put it to a default template location.

Now, every time I open a new document (whether default New Document or New from Template…), styles for Headings (and several other defined styles) keep resetting to blue color and Calibri font. I expect them to keep be black and Tahoma, exactly as I defined them in Normal.dotm (if I re-open the template file for editing, styles are defined properly there).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

### The Normal.dotm template needs to be stored in the User Templates Folder

**Unless you have modified your settings, this will be a different folder from the default templates folder.**

Find the template you have stored as Normal.dotm in your default templates folder and create a new document based on your template. Do NOT move that template! I am almost certain it is not a fully functional normal template.

You can do this with File > New and go to your custom templates. Look for Normal.dotm.

Check to see if the styles are the way you saved them.

If they are, use the [Styles Organizer](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Organizer) to copy them to the functional Normal.dotm template. Or you could create a [Quick] Styles Set under the Design tab. Here is [my article on such style sets](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/quick-style-sets-and-word-themes-in-microsoft-word/444d4195-a28a-43bb-b035-facd84f7bd44).

Here is my page on [locating](https://addbalance.com/word/normaltemplate.htm#Find) and [opening](https://addbalance.com/word/normaltemplate.htm#Open) the Normal.dotm template.

Here is [my page on the Default Templates Folder and the User Templates Folder](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fileNew.htm#Distinction).